# Wrong page reference of bibliography

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to make a page reference to my bibliography, but it refers to the last page of the bibliography (page 2 e.g.). I assume it's because the label in the master document is after the bibliography input. Is it possible to refer to a previous page using `\pageref{}`, (page 1 e.g.)??

I assume a code isn't necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: The values delivered by `pageref` are nothing that can be counted etc. with. You need `\getpagerefnumber` from `refcount` package to handle this or provide a better label position. Without any seeing compilable code, this is hard to solve, so your assumption that the code is not necessary is wrong ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just to be sure, I can't use e.g. \pageref{(my label)} and the substract one page?

Comment: Yes, `\pageref` is not expandable, i.e. you can't use its output and process it again other than just typeset it. You need something like `\the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{yourlabel}-1`, where `yourlabel` is the relevant label you provided for the bibliography page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve this 'manipulation', but this would give wrong links if `hyperref` is used (although `\getpagerefnumber` does not provide links at all, so this is no real issue)

Since I don't have the real document at hand, I 'invented' a use case and modify the number that would be reported by `\pageref`.

However, `\pageref` is an unexpandable command, so the values reported by it can't be used again other than typesetting them. The package `refcount` provides the `\getpagerefnumber` command which gives the direct entry of the page-entry in the `\newlabel` found in the `.aux` file.

The rest consists of a `\the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{somelabelname}-1` to subtract a value of `1` and displaying this as 'page' reference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

So, now the real page number is \pageref{section::foobar} but we manipulate it to print \the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{section::foobar}-1, which is weird, of course ;-)

\section{Foo section}
\blindtext[10]
\section{Foo bar section}\label{section::foobar}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In general, I would rather fix the label position however than to modify the page reference

Comment: Thanks, this was just the solution I was looking fore! At this particular problem I would prefere not to change the label position :-)

Comment: @Rasmus: I see -- happy TeXing!